# SAS rotate table 90 degree then output to pdf

Tags: sas, proc

Currently I use following code to output pdf.

```
GOPTIONS device=ACTXIMG;
ods pdf file="....\Daily Performance &CDate..pdf";

title 'Daily Performance';
proc tabulate data=DailyReport s=[just=c] missing;
class Area Period/order=data preloadfmt;
format Area $Areaformat. Period $Periodformat.;
var Units Uti Vari;
table (Area='' ),
      (Units={Label="Units"}*(mean=''*f=comma6.)
       Uti={Label="Uti"}*(sum=''*f=percent8.1)
       Vari={Label="Var."}*(mean=''*f=percent8.1))/box="&CDate";
run;

ods pdf close;
```

But in some cases I have 20-30 columns in a tabulated output. If I use above code, then the table will be break into 2 or more pages in PDF.

So Is there a way to make it "vertical" in pdf? Or a way to keep it horizontal while compressed into one-page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your page orientation using option orientation.

```
option orientation=landscape;
```

You change change the orientation within the document by changing the option between procs.

Comment: 30 columns is a lot to fit on a page, other solutions would be to change your style to minimize your white space, change font so that things are smaller, or to simply split your table in a way that you have control of.